# Missing multi currency feature in Organization while installing manage package?

Tags: apex, managed-package

Our manage package is not supporting an org which is not enabled multicurrency. To provide the multicurrency support we are checking for multicurrency is enabled or not.

```
Boolean isMultiCurrencyEnabled =  UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization();
```

We are putting this check before using `CurrencyIsoCode`, `IsoCode`, `CurrencyType`, `DatedConversionRate`.
Please let me know how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 4):

To "kill" the dependency you need to examine your code. You must have no compile-time references to currency-related fields.

- Do you have dynamic SOQL (`Database.query('SELECT CurrencyIsoCode FROM Opportunity');`) all over the place?
- Do you have Dynamic Apex (`String code = (String) opp.get('CurrencyIsoCode');`) everywhere?
- Do your custom objects have any `Currency` fields?

That kind of stuff. I had the same when I had to make conditional Chatter support - I had to kill all compiled references to `FeedItem` object.

Try going to your packaging screen -> view dependencies button. If you're lucky it should list something in Org-level dependencies. Maybe even object-specific ones will contain info which currency field seems to be hardcoded. (this is a funny feature, might be good idea to compile all classes before going here)

[image]

Comment: It means if I am using any custom currency field, in that case, I should go with the number instead of currency. Am I right?

Comment: I didn't try it but that would be my guess. Check what this packaging dependencies screen says, both org level and object level